# share variable between classes and methods

Tags: python, python-2.7

Im pretty new to OOP languages and I have a scenario where I want to share a variable between two classes that both have methods. In class One I have a function with a variable var1. I would like to make that variable available to my class Two, func2 however I'm not sure how to make this happen ?

```
class One(object):

    def func1(self):
        var1 = 'foo'

class Two(object):

    def func2(self):
    # how can i get var1 here ?
```

Comment: You need to either pass the variable to the method, or one of the classes can inherit from the other and thus get it's variables, but this is assuming you understand OOP enough to know the difference between the abstract class itself vs. an instantiated object (as shown the variable only exists in the method's local scope vs. defining it in an `__init__` method). You could also make it a global variable or part of a third class object that One and Two both use. Hard to say with `One` and `Two` and no understanding of the actual data relationship(s).

Comment: It's also possible that you want `var1` to be an instance variable rather than a local variable (e.g .`self.var1 = 'foo'`). Then `func2` could access its value if it had a reference to an instance of `One` (though where that instance would come from is impossible to say given how abstract this question is).

Comment: You will get much better answers if you make this less abstract so that the relationship between `One` and `Two` (if any) is understood (choose an analogous relationship if the real one is confidential).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one of the classes can actually be a sub-class of another class, you can use inheritance.

```
class One(object):

    def func1(self):
        var1 = 'foo'

class Two(One):

    # func1 already exists here.
    # So does var1
```

You can make the function accept arguments

```
class One(object):

    def func1(self):
        var1 = 'foo'

class Two(object):

    def func2(self, var):
        # Use var
```

Or you can use global variables but I think you want to avoid this if you are just entering OOP.

**Note:** Let me point out that using global variables in bigger projects and programs prone to many errors in practice. You can use it until you have the experience to move on to another method. But eventually you will have to quit using them in OOP. I suggested it just for practice purposes. Keep that in mind while coding.

**Edit:** In your case, you may want to use static class elements, such as.

```
class One(object):
    var1 = "foonimo"
    def func1(self):
        #use var1

class Two(object):

    def func2(self, var):
        # Use as One.var1
```

This should work, and it is more feasible than global variables.

Comment: 1. The first one is pointless, if OP wants to overload the method. 2. `you can use global variables` – this is what I'm actually down-voting for.

Comment: @EliKorvigo  Which I advised to avoid, however you cannot deny it is an option.

Comment: He's a newbie, hence I'd have put a lot more emphasis on that advice.

Comment: The inheritance method I was aware of, however I am using a framework that does not seem to like it when I use that that option. Global variables can work. One thing I I'm still trying to learn with python OOP is why can pass variables to other classes when I don't have a method but when I have the method things get way more complicated. for example if I was in class Two I could just type 'new_var = One.var1' and that should work

Comment: @bytes1234 In that case, let me make another edit. See if it suits you.

Comment: Thanks for all your kind replies Rockabilly. The static element scenario is what I just commented on. What Im really trying to learn is passing the variables between classes that have methods. I seen you one of your comments where you mention I could give the methods arguments. This is something that can be done but not sure how manageable it is ?

Comment: Well there is no other way to pass some data to a function which is in another class. You have to plan your program structure according to that, which a function in a class accepts variables safely.(If you do it correct, it is always manageable, though I cannot specifically say because I don't know the actual function.) Static variables is usually more useful when dealing with a non-changing data which needs to be used over and over.